# How can I return a class choosing between 2 classes?

Tags: java, class, return

I wanted to know if is it possible to have a method that can choose between multiple classes and return one of them.

This is what it should look like:

```
public class BotManager {
public static Test test;
public static int PROTOCOL_VERSION = 114;

public Bot bot(){
    if(PROTOCOL_VERSION == 114){
        return test.bot114;
    }else{
        return test.bot111;
    }
}
```

in this example, bot111 and bot114 are different classes.

bot.version111.bot.Bot;

bot.version114.bot.Bot;

Comment: If the two returned classes have nothing in common how is a caller of the method supposed to use the result in any meaningful way?

Comment: I think you should read about [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Comment: I suspect neither is a class, but instances of different classes.. so these must implement the same interface or extend the same class. (or the method's return type must be `Object`, which mostly is not very useful)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah of course you can.
You just need to be sure that `bot114` and `bot111` both extend the `Bot` class.

For these purposes you would use what's called a factory, here is an example of a factory that returns different Windows based on the Class type:

```java
  public static Window getCsvExportWindow(Class tab) {
        if (tab == OnhandTab.class) {
            return new OnhandCsvExportWindow();
        } else {
            return new CustOrderCsvExportWindow();
        }
   }
```

Instead of Class type you use your PROTOCOL_VERSION.

Comment: by the question they are both `Bot`, but from different packages: `bot.version111.bot.Bot`
and
`bot.version114.bot.Bot`

Answer (score -2):

You can use it's code:

```
if (Object object instanceof Bot114) {
  return new Bot114();
} else if (Object object instanceof Bot111) {
  return new Bot111();
} else {
  return null;
}
```

Comment: `Object object instanceof Bot114` does not make any sense. And returning `null` is a bad practice. And what is the return type of the method? And how is a caller supposed to call it and use the result?

Comment: in no way does that address the questions problem (e.g. class is selected by value of `PROTOCOL_VERSION`)